# network analysis in eclipse ide of java Client Server Program

Tags: java, eclipse, iot, coap, network-analysis

I have client and Server program written in java. I want to calculate packet delivery ration, throughput, RTT and other network related parameter for network analysis of client and server. I am using Eclipse neon IDE.

I also want to verify how many packets are transmitted from client to server, how many of them are get response and how many packet are dropped by server.

Client and Server are based on application layer protocol protocol(CoAP).

Comment: This is a statement of intent, not a question. Did you have a question?

Comment: Question is how can we track request going from client to server in Eclipse IDE? How can we calculate number of packet successfully receive response from server? Using ether eclipse or any code of java?